# The body in/on his windshield

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

He got out of the car. Looked up at the building, then at the body **in/on** his windshield.

If the body is lying outside his windshield, should it be ***in*** or ***on***?

Comment: Small objects can be embedded in a windshield, but you don't speak about large things being *in* a windshield, like a body. That's because bodies go *through* windshields, and don't stay stuck in them. You would use *on* if the body is lying across the windshield. Also, your second sentence is missing a subject.

Answer (score 0):

If the windshield is still in one piece (if possibly shattered), and the body lies on top of it, *on* is the right choice.

*In* could be used if, for instance, the body has fallen hard enough to pierce the windshield and get embedded in it.

Comment: Agreed that it's **on** or **(draped) across** the windshield. But I doubt **in** because this would imply that the body was somehow contained in the windshield. Possibly **through** the shattered windshield.